# JQuery append image

Tags: jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to move the thumbnail image below the summary title. Here's my code. Currently nothing happens. Any suggestions? Thank you!

JQuery

```
 $(".summary-thumbnail-image" ).insertBefore( ".summary-excerpt" );
```

HTML

```
<div class="summary-item">
<a href="/blog/gathering" class="summary-thumbnail-container">
<div class="summary-thumbnail">
<img src="gathering.jpg" class="summary-thumbnail-image">
</div>
</a>

<div class="summary-title">...</div>

<div class="summary-excerpt">...</div></div>
```

Comment: your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/ .. be sure to include Jquery if you forgot to include it ... and you can use $(".summary-thumbnail-image" ).insertAfter( ".summary-title" ); .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vLjyw2ks/1/

Comment: The actual markup is a bit different - I tried to abbreviate here but it doesn't work - http://www.girlmeetsisland.com/new-home

Comment: see my answer .. hope it help

Comment: @mohamed-yousef thank you it works! excellent

Comment: glad it help .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.summary-item').each(function(){
     var ThisIt = $(this);
     ThisIt.find('.summary-thumbnail-container').insertAfter(ThisIt.find('.summary-title'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.html()` :

```
$(".summary-thumbnail-image" ).html().insertBefore( ".summary-excerpt" );
```